# Difference between Syntax of for Loops to append data to create a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list of lists by appending data from a dataset

**First way**

```
transactions=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,20)
        transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j])])
```

**Second way**

```
transactions=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,20)])
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: there is also another way, completely with list comprehensions, but what is the question exactly?

Comment: Suppose there is a dataset and i want to create a list of lists.Each list element should contain a unique row of the dataset. The  second method does this,but the first method appends each  element of each row in a downward fashion.